# Getting cookies via Selenium and php

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I want to find out (via PHP) which third-party cookies are set when you visit a particular site, for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

I understand that one can use Selenium to do that, but I can't find any info about exactly how it's done.

Do you know how to get all cookie data from a webpage by using Selenium via php?

Like:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.se";
// ..... run the webpage with a non graphic browser ......
$cookies = all_cookies;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which PHP bindings you are using.

If you are using [PHP WebDriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) from facebook, then you can do

```
// get all cookies
$driver->manage()->getCookies()
```

([source](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/1096e1786b2733069c220ff9c7a7ebebe64afdc2/example.php#L20))